# Remove attribute html in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have problem with remove the attribute `class="active"` in tag `li`.

I have 2 class in tag `<li>`.

One is: active,

another one is: dropdown

but i just want to remove the previous `class="active"` and add this to the tag `<li>` when I clicked it.
 But when I remove, the `class="dropdown"` also removed.

I know my code have problem but I dont know how to fix it.

Can anybody help me :)

Sorry, because my english not good :)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li class="dropdown">
         <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
              Dropdown
              <span class="caret"></span>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
             <li>Hoai Thy</li>
             <li>My Huyen</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
    $(".nav-justified li").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $(".nav-justified li").removeAttr();
        $(this).attr("class","active");
     });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

An answer based on `toggleClass` has claready been posted.  Alterntivate is to remove and add classes as you are trying to do but in jQuery do that via `removeClass` and `addClass`, not via attr.  There could be other (pure presentation) classes that you want to leave unaltered).

```
$(".nav-justified li").click(function(){
   $(".nav-justified li").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Also, you don't need the `.each()` - `.click(function(){})` binds the event to all elements in the collection

Comment: Its complete answer. +1 for proper event binding

Answer (score 1):

Use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of removing attribute and adding the attribute again:

```
$(".nav-justified li").toggleClass('active');
```

---

And removeAttr() method won't remove the class name but it removes the whole attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.removeClass()` to remove class.also use `.addClass()` to add class active.Try this:

```
 $(this).click(function(){
    $(".nav-justified li.active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: You should also use `addClass()` instead of `attr()` to set the class

Answer (score 0):

This will Work for you.

```
    $(".nav-justified li").each(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active')
     });
```